# Upload file in OpenRasta using PUT

Tags: .net, rest, file-upload, openrasta

Is it possible to upload a file in OpenRasta using the PUT post method?

Comment: Dangerously similar to the other question you just asked... Though not identical...

Comment: I thought it best to split them up in to shorter, specific questions, than one big, all purpose question.

Comment: Agreed. However, some people may only read the titles (yes, I see they are different, but some people vote by gut reaction)... I suggest to wait a bit before posting multiple related questions.

Comment: Good point, will do in future.

Comment: Good thing I read the question before I vote :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question with multiple answers here.

If you want to do that with an html form, you'll have to add a uri decorator to enable detection of methods that are not supported by html (HttpMethodUriDecorator I think), and then append "!METHOD" to the URI you pass in the form@action attrivute.

Then you can do your binding as usual.

If you want to do it from a standard http client, application/octet-stream should be enough, maybe with the content-disposition header (I can't quite remmeber if the IFile type is processed when using application/octet-stream).